# Translation in free mode is not working for newly added entries in accordion grid element in typo3

Tags: typo3, accordion, language-translation, typo3-11.x, tx-gridelements

I am  doing some translation practice in typo3 version 11.5.6.
I have 2 languages first in english(default) and second is german. I given free mode to german language, and i have one accordion grid element.

The problem is when i create grid element in default launguage and add some content after that translation works fine but when i add new content element in previous grid then translation is not working.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is currently no official Gridelements version for CMS 11 available, you will either have to wait until the public release of GE 11 or you could join the group of sponsors of the crowd funding campaign to get early access to the current development state.